# Sorting a std::vector of std::pair's using user defined compare class

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, c++11, vector

I have two class templates `MyClassA<T>` and `MyClassB<T>`.

From these, I have constructed two `std::vector`'s as `std::vector<MyClassA<double>> A` and `std::vector<MyClassB<double>> B`.

My goal is to first sort `A` in ascending order (in actual I will do a range/partial sort).

Then using that order to sort `B`.

What I am doing so far is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <random>

// my class definitions
template<typename T>
class MyClassA
{
public:
    T valA;
};

template<typename T>
class MyClassB
{
public:
    T valB;
};

// my compare class
template<typename T>
using TIter = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

template <typename T>
class MyCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(std::pair<std::size_t, TIter<MyClassA<T>>>
           const& a, std::pair<std::size_t, TIter<MyClassA<T>>> const& b)
    {
        return *(a.second).valA < *(b.second).valA;
    }
};

// sort from given order
//... not yet implemented

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    // first ClassA Object vector A
    std::vector<MyClassA<double>> A(5);
    for(auto& i:A) i.valA = dis(gen);
    // second ClassB Object vector B
    std::vector<MyClassB<double>> B(5);
    for(auto& i:B) i.valB = dis(gen);

    // sort vector A elements' references in ascending order
    std::size_t i = 0;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, TIter<MyClassA<double>>>> torder(A.size());
    for(auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); ++it, ++i) torder[i] = std::make_pair(i, it);
    std::sort(torder.begin(), torder.end(), MyCompare<double>()); // getting error here

    // sort vectors A and B elements using the above sorted order
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

`error: 'const class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MyClassA<double>*, std::vector<MyClassA<double> > >' has no member named 'valA'`

Comment: How are you doing the sorting, `std::sort`?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: If you have asked about sorting vector A, then I have edited above. Yes, `std::sort` will actually not sort `std::vector` `A` itself, but it will sort the references only. (Good question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple case of problem with the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The member selection dot `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator, so e.g. `*(a.second).valA` is parsed as `*((a.second).valA)`.

Simply change to e.g. `a.second->valA` (or `(*a.second).valA`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hell I wasted so much time!

Answer (score 1):

```
return *(a.second).valA < *(b.second).valA;
```

`a.second` and `b.second` appears to be iterators, so this should simply be:

```
return (a.second)->valA < (b.second)->valA;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hell I wasted so much time!